# jQuery ajax DELETE not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

The following part of my code doesn't work:

```
           $("body").on("click", "a", function(){

                var ID = $(this).attr("id");
                $.ajax({
                    url: url + '?' + $.param({"id": ID}),
                    type: 'DELETE',
                    success: function(){alert("Entry deleted");}
                });

            });
```

More specifically, it's the ajax request that isn't working. No alert-message is shown after clicking on one of the "Delete" links, so apparently the ajax-request wasn't successful.

The whole code looks as follows (for some context):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de-DE">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
      body {
        font: 15px normal Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #000000;
      }
      label {
        width: 5em;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      ul {
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

        var url = "https://vsr.informatik.tu-chemnitz.de/edu/2015/evs/exercises/jsajax/guestbook.php";

        /******Code to show the content of the server file: *******************/            
          $.get(url, function(data){

          var table = document.createElement("table");
          $("body").append(table);
          var tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
          $("table").append(tbody);

          for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            $("tbody").append("<tr><td>" + data[i]["name"] + "</td><td>" + data[i]["text"] + "</td><td><a id=\"" + data[i]["id"] + "\" href=\"\">Delete</a></td></tr>");  
          }

        });
        /****************************************************************************

          *****Code to delete an entry (with a specified id) in the server file:****/ 

            $("body").on("click", "a", function(){

            var ID = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
              url: url + '?' + $.param({"id": ID}),
              type: 'DELETE',
              //success: function(){$(this).closest("tr").remove();}
              success: function(){alert("test");}
            });

          });

        /**********************************************************************/


      });          
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Guestbook</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><b>TestUser:</b> This is an example entry. <a href="#" alt="Delete entry">(X)</a></li>
      <li><b>TestUser2:</b> This is another example entry. <a href="#" alt="Delete entry">(X)</a></li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <form method="POST" action="https://vsr.informatik.tu-chemnitz.de/edu/2015/evs/exercises/jsajax/guestbook.php">
      <label for="name">Name</label> <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name"><br>
      <label for="text">Text</label> <input id="text" type="text" name="text" placeholder="Text"><br>
      <button type="submit">Add entry</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

*****************************UPDATE***************************

Here's a screenshot from the network-part of my Developer-Tools after pressing one of the "Delete"-links:

[image]

If I'm not mistaken, there aren't any error messages shown anywhere ...

Comment: Learn to debug, open your developer tools, go to the network tab, click **XHR** to show only your XHR requests, then perform your delete action and take a look at what the actual response from the server looks like.

Comment: What do you see in the developer tools? What messages or errors do you get? You should use some basic debugging techniques to help here.

Comment: There aren't any messages in the console .. that's one of the things I don't get ...

Comment: Is your endpoint configured to allow DELETE?  (many aren't due to issues in older versions of IE).  How are you checking the your service is being hit?

Comment: Currently you're not checking for errors so they won't be shown. What do you get if you add an `error: function(){alert("error");}` to your ajax call?

Comment: @Tommy - Click on the request in your network tab, then click the **Response** header to see what the server sent you back. Close your `console` (esc), you don't need it open to debug the response from the request.

Comment: That's weird, you're getting a `200` response back from the server, which is a success code, there's no reason that you're success callback (the alert) should not be getting called.

Comment: I edited adding the snippet, when click in delete (there's a cancelation before, this happens for you too?)

Comment: @Adam: Where can I click on a "Response" header under  my Network tab? I can't see sth like that?

Comment: Click the request. **...**

Comment: I can't click the request because it disappears after the alert-box is gone. While the alert-box is there, I can't click on it either, because it's not responsive ... see the last part of my question above (after the second "UPDATE")

Comment: `return false` after your AJAX request, your browser is navigating to a new page because you clicked on a link.

Comment: @andrepaulo yes exactly, the request is getting cancelled (see the last part of my question with the screenshot) .. the question is how can I avoid the cancellation?

Comment: @Tommy - see my comment. `return false` from your click handler (right after your AJAX request).

Comment: @Adam Sorry I didn't understand your last comment ... what shall I do? ... shall I add the line "return false" somewhere ?

Comment: @Tommy - right after your `$.ajax({...})` lines, add the line `return false;`

Comment: perfect @Adam... the return false after the ajax will make it work!

Comment: @Adam You are my star! It now works ....

Comment: @Adam I have no idea why it works ... what does adding "return false" having to do with anything?

Comment: @Adam Thank you very much for your answer ... I get it now ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your page was not sending the AJAX request because it was immediately navigating away from the current page when you clicked on a link (the browser's default action).

`return false` at the end of your click handler (or, you can re-write it like this):

```
$('body').on('click','a',function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   //rest of your code
});
```

Comment: Could not doing e.default theoretically cause a 404 error?